# Rails 3 routing question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Project model that has_many :workers. In routes.rb, workers are a nested resource for projects:

```
    resources :projects do
            resources :workers
    end
```

I would like to make it so that when a user goes to the path

```
'/project_name'
```

they're routed to the show action for the project with that name.

And when a user goes to the path

```
'/project_name/workers/worker_id'
```

they're routed to the show action for the worker with that id.

I would also like to make it so that `project_worker_path(@project, @worker)` routes to

```
'/project_name/workers/worker_id'
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: what's wrong with your routes? it looks okay to me...what happens when you go to those urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but I believe the following will work.

In routes.rb:

```
resources :projects, :path => '/' do
  resources :workers
end
```

In project.rb:

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

In projects_controller.rb:

```
@project = Project.find_by_name(params[:id])
```

In workers_controller.rb:

```
@project = Project.find_by_name(params[:project_id])
```

Basically, `to_param` is used to generate the url, and `:path => '/'` tells it that you don't want anything to come before the parameter. This will also map the root path to `projects#index` if that's what you want it to do. You can turn that part off by passing `:except => :index` to `resources`.

Answer (score 0):

As one of your later routes you need to add something like:

```
# config/routes.rb
match ':project_id/workers/:worker_id(.:format)', :to => 'workers#show'
match ':project_id(.:format)', :to => 'projects#show'
```